# PGN replayer should not require FEN header

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

There was a note in the answer about how to use the FEN/PGN replayer about why pasting a PGN requires an FEN header:

> This was done in order to create an "opt-in" experience for the replayers (i.e. only display a replayer if you actively choose to have one), but this is open for debate.

IMHO, this solution is excessively cumbersome, and should be changed for two reasons.

First, I think it's very rare for people to paste PGN games without wanting the replayer. I can't really think of many contexts where that makes sense, other than questions about PGN format itself. Forcing the user to "opt-in" by adding this irritating (and unmemorable) string `[FEN ""]` is just an excessive burden.

Second, the necessity to paste a PGN inside a code block means that it is *already* an opt-in experience. That is, if you wanted to, include a PGN without the replayer, you can just type it in without the code block (with a backslash to avoid list formatting):

1. f4 e5 2. g4 Qh4#

Could this please be changed?

Comment: `[FEN ""]` is an excessive burden?  I think our definitions of "excessive" and "burden" may be very different.

Comment: Every time I want to add a game I need to go and search for how to do it, because (as noted), that string is not sufficiently memorable. I doubt I'm alone in this. So yes, having to open another tab, go and search for the code block (which, until I just edited that post, was still not easy to find), copy and paste it - does that meet your threshold for these two words?

Comment: Appreciate the response.  I keep a SE "bookmark" on the meta page and/or refer to one of my posts with the replayer if I need a refresher.  I'll consider your point and post an answer if I feel I can add value to the discussion.

Comment: Also, highlighting that the original quote said specifically **this is open for debate**.